# Html Get the selectedindex value and persist it even after the page reloads

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-select

I have a dropdownlist in html like this,

```
<select onchange="redirect(this.value)"> 
    <option>choose a category</option> 
    <option>Business</option>    
    <option>Music</option>
    <option>Sports</option>
    <option>Cause</option> 
    <option>Politics</option> 
</select>
```

My Javascript code for redirecting to another page content:

```
<script>
  function redirect(ddcategory){ 
    window.location= ddcategory;
  } 
</script>
```

The redirection is working but how to have the selected option in dropdown list to persist even after the page loads.

For example, when I select **Music** the music page loads but the value in category dropdown changes back to **choose a category**;  how to set it to the selected value?

Please solve this problem.

Comment: Use cookie, or an additional query parameter (e.g. `?ddcat=val`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use the [localStorage-Feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) which even persists longer then the browser session. in my link you even have a fallback for browsers not supporting localstorage (using cookies).

```
// set the ddcat
localStorage.setItem('ddcat', 'yourddcat value');

// get the ddcat
var ddcategory = localStorage.getItem('ddcat');
```

if you only want this feature in the current session, use the 'sessionStorage'

Comment: now its storing the ddcat item in the localStorage element to the value i selected(eg.Music)...what show i do now to set this the dropdownlist select value..and where should i get this item...

Comment: use a domready handler (eg: https://github.com/ded/domready), when the dom is ready read your category from the localStorage, and set your select to that value (if present). question: why do you do that client-side? do you only have static pages? if you have a client-side scripting language (php, ruby, java, asp) you should do stuff like that on the server

Answer (score 0):

i think you can solve this problem with sessions.its possible with ajax or any programming langs.
set selection to session on onchange function and set selected option from session on load

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variable in session storage before moving to the page,

then on Load of the page implement the changes in drop down list

```
  function redirect(ddcategory){ 
    sessionStorage["MyChoise"]= ddcategory;
    window.location= ddcategory;
  }
```

On Load page:

```
function OnLoadPage()
{
   //Select your element from the session 
}
```